# second order differential equation 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve this equation and reached to below answer but I think it needs to some recheck.please help me to get sure of this differential equation :
$
2y^{2}y''+2y(y')^{2}=1
$

my guess for this equation is :

$y'=z$ and $y''=z\dfrac{dz}{dy}$ so the I got : $2y^{2}z\dfrac{dz}{dy}+2yz^{2}=1$ => $2y^{2}zdz+(2yz^{2}-1)dy=0$

with solving this equation => $y^{2}z^{2}-y=c$ by assuming that $z=y'$ then I got $y^{2}(y')^{2}-y=c$ so by changing some place I got this : $y'= \sqrt{\dfrac{c+y}{y^{2}}}$ and finally getting :

$
x=\int \sqrt{\dfrac{y^{2}}{c+y}}dy
$

> note : I don't need the answer of integration

Comment: Try putting you guess back into equation :).

Comment: i think the solution looks very ugly, have you tried Wolfram-alpha?

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner : i didn't check it on Wolfram-alpha but i set my solution on...can you please take a look on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2yy''+2y'^2=1/y\\
(2yy')'=1/y\\
(y^2)''=y^{-1}\\  
z=y^2\\z''z'=z^{-1/2}z'\\
(z')^2=4\sqrt{z}+4c\\
x=\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{4\sqrt{z}+4c}}\\=\int\frac{y}{\sqrt{y+c}}dy
$$
This agrees with you.  The integral is easy, substitute $y+c=u$

Comment: I completed my solution by writing it step by step can you please take a look on it...

Comment: can you please explain what did mentioned by $(y^{2})''=y^{-1}$

Comment: Yes, your solution looks correct to me.

Comment: I'm very doubtful about my last two step I mean : $y'= \sqrt{\dfrac{c+y}{y^{2}}}$ and $x=\int \sqrt{\dfrac{y^{2}}{c+y}}dy$

Answer (score 0):

$$
2y'' + \frac{2}{y}y'^2 = \dfrac{d}{dy}y'^2 + \frac{2}{y}y'^2 = \frac{1}{y^2}
$$
Let $p =y'^2$ we find
$$
\dfrac{dp}{dy} +\frac{2}{y}p = \frac{1}{y^2}
$$
Using integrating factor we find
$$
py^2 = \int \frac{1}{y^2} y^2 dy + C
$$
Thus we get 
$$
p=y'^2= \frac{y+C}{y^2}
$$
So you look correct.

Comment: I completed my solution by writing it step by step can you please take a look on it...